# Speed limits with HERE REST API with PDE

Tags: routing, extents, here-maps

I've looked into stack overflow for questions similar to mine, namely HERE Maps API - get speed limit of all roads in a tile?

So this effectively means that https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing/link-information-for-a-location will be deprecated, correct?

I also understand that the [PDE](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/pde.html) is the way to go.

However, I couldn't find a simple example on the API Playground (just a simple REST call) that shows how to perform that functionality, e.g. get speed limits for a road.

Is anyone able to provide some clearance? I've read about the key concepts such as tiles and layers but it is quite overwhelming.

Comment: you can use a bounding box to get the speed limits within an area (grid square) like https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=52.5168%2C13.3885&waypoint1=52.5166%2C13.3935&mode=fastest%3Bcar&viewbounds=52.5178%2C13.3856%3B52.5159%2C13.3928&representation=linkPaging&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

Comment: but that is going to be deprecated in end of March, hence my question

Comment: Not had any notification on this and we are premium subscribers , you will have to migrate if they are.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656152/here-maps-api-get-speed-limit-of-all-roads-in-a-tile 

the answer to this question is why I am stating the functionality will be deprecated. However, I'm brand new to this API so I'm trying to understand what are the proper steps to use the PDE. But I do not find any information on the website on that functionality being deprecated in the future

Answer (score 1):

There's an example in PHP for getting a speed limit for a location using the PDE here:

https://github.com/seaBass3/here-pde-speed-limit/blob/master/Here_PDE_Demo.php

```
<?php
//To run this example use the following URL
//{Your Domain}/Here_PDE_Demo.php?coords={"lat": 30.192327, "lng": -81.727523}


if ($_GET['coords']) {
    $coords = json_decode($_GET['coords'], true);

    $ch = curl_init("https://reverse.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=" . $coords['lat'] . "," . $coords['lng'] . ",50&mode=retrieveAddresses&locationAttributes=linkInfo&gen=9&app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
    curl_close($ch);

    if (gettype($data) == "array") {
        $ReferenceId = $data["Response"]["View"][0]["Result"][0]["Location"]["MapReference"]["ReferenceId"];
        $functionClass = $data["Response"]["View"][0]["Result"][0]["Location"]["LinkInfo"]["FunctionalClass"];

        if (isset($ReferenceId) && isset($functionClass)) {
            $level = 8 + $functionClass;
            $tileSize = 180 / pow(2, $level);
            $tileY = (int)(($coords['lat'] + 90) / $tileSize);
            $tileX = (int)(($coords['lng'] + 180) / $tileSize);

            $ch = curl_init("https://pde.api.here.com/1/tile.json?layer=SPEED_LIMITS_FC" . (string)$functionClass . "&tilex=" . $tileX . "&tiley=" . $tileY . "&level=9&app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $pde = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
            curl_close($ch);

            if (gettype($pde) == "array") {
                $pdeLength = count($pde["Rows"]);
                $txt = "No Speed found for supplied location";
                for ($i = 0; $i < $pdeLength; $i++) {
                    if ($pde["Rows"][$i]["LINK_ID"] == $ReferenceId) {
                        if ($pde["Rows"][$i]["FROM_REF_SPEED_LIMIT"]) {
                            $Speed = floatval($pde["Rows"][$i]["FROM_REF_SPEED_LIMIT"]);
                            $Speed = (int)($Speed * 0.621371); //convert from KPH to MPH
                            $txt = $Speed . "mph";
                        } elseif ($pde["Rows"][$i]["TO_REF_SPEED_LIMIT"]) {
                            $Speed = floatval($pde["Rows"][$i]["TO_REF_SPEED_LIMIT"]);
                            $Speed = (int)($Speed * 0.621371); //convert from KPH to MPH
                            $txt = $Speed . "mph";
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }
                echo $txt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've convered this to C# previously and found it worked well.